# After installing Xcode, where is the Clang compiler?

Tags: xcode, macos

I installed the newest version of Xcode.

Neither of the executables `gcc`, `cc`, or `clang` exist in the terminal.

How can I find the C compiler in the terminal that Xcode uses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such commands have been made into a separate "command-line tools" package as of Xcode 4.3 or thereabouts.

They have been moved into the *Xcode.app* bundle as part of making Xcode a more standard [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)) install. The separate CLI tools is also [useful for projects like Homebrew](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html) which have no need for the full Xcode download.

To install ([from here](http://holgr.com/blog/2012/02/xcode-4-3-and-homebrew-where-did-my-command-line-tools-go/)):

> - Open Xcode
> - Go to Preferences
> - Select Downloads and click Install for Command Line Tools (about 171 megabyte)
>
> [image: Xcode command line tools Download page screenshot]

Answer (score 43):

Type in [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal):

```
xcodebuild -find make
xcodebuild -find gcc
xcodebuild -find g++
xcodebuild -find clang
xcodebuild -find clang++
```

Each command prints the full path to the corresponding tool. They are the ones that are used by Xcode.

You can also install *Xcode Command Line Tools* which will place tools and libraries under standard Unix locations (`/usr/bin`, `/usr/include`, etc.) if you want to be able to just type `make` or `gcc` without any paths. Note that these tools will be unrelated to the ones that Xcode application uses and may be of different versions.

Comment: It will just tell me where are those "clang.. clang++..." or do things such as link them?

Answer (score 6):

It seems to have moved:

```
xcodebuild -find clang
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
```

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer (although helpful), this answer actually answers the OP's question of >how can I find the C compiler... that Xcode uses?

Answer (score 1):

It's in Xcode app bundle:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

If executables `gcc`, `cc`, and `clang` are available on the command line, you can get information about the installation and the directory by the `-v` tag.

```
gcc -v
cc -v
clang -v
```

Comment: Re *"tag"*: Do you mean *"option"*?