# Error installing Cython because of added white space

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, cython

I am currently running iPython on two separate computers (a laptop running Mac OS 10.7.5 and a desktop running Mac OS 10.8.4) and would like to install Cython to speed things up. On my laptop everything went smoothly: I downloaded Cython then ran the `$python setup.py install` command from the Cython directory and Cython installed immediately.

However, things are not going quite so smoothly on my desktop. The first issue was that I did not previously have gcc on the computer. However, downloading the latest version of Xcode should have solved that problem. Now when I run the `$python setup.py install` command, everything works fine until the install starts `building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension` from within the `python.py` file located in my iPython directory. The issue is that the command which the install automatically inputs reads `/ A p p l i c a t i o n s / X c o d e . a p p / C o n t e n t s / ... / u s r / b i n / c l a n g` and so on. I then get an error message which reads `command '/' failed with exit status 1`. Clearly the issue is the added white space in the directory path.

I do not know why this white space is there and I do not know how to tell the computer to look in the proper directory (the one without the spaces). If anybody could please help it would be greatly appreciated. I should also note that I did not have this problem on my laptop because the proper executables were located directly in my `/usr/bin` directory. I do not trust that I know enough about what I'm doing to manually move the proper executables from within the Xcode package contents to the `/usr/bin` directory, though that seems like a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is having the same issue, I was able to fix it. I will actually link to the response on this site that answered this for me:

[After install Xcode, where is clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228382/after-install-xcode-where-is-clang)

Once I installed the Command Line Tools manually, all of the proper executables were put in my `/usr` directory and running the `$python setup.py install` command worked immediately. They should really install the Command Line Tools when you install Xcode...